# Not able to upload apk file at Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Hope you all are well.

I want to upload my application in android market.but it show me an error

```
The certificate that signed this apk is not valid until the future.Create a new certificate.
```

I followed this steps: Android Tools > Export signed Application Package

my system time show correct time can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my system date before 2 days and it's working. thanks for reply...

Answer (score 1):

Take a deep look at your certificate, and see when the validity starts (from the error message, most likely in a close future). Then either :

- make sure your computer date is correct, (timezone and all), and try again.
- wait until your certificate is valid, and upload your app again

Answer (score 0):

Create a new certificate/sign key, your old one has probably expired.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the developer guide for publishing market applications you have to create a certificate thats valid for **~25 years**. Probably you didn't set this parameter and your certificate is expired.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:-

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing my systemclock's date to -2 days. Then I created a new certificate with the same parameters. It worked fine.